# React Axios response cannot be parsed into datatables

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new to React, I've built a Go backend and tried to create React frontend.

```
let usersData = []
axios
  .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/monitor/list`)
  .then((res) => {
    usersData = res.data;
  })
```

The datatables says no result.
But when I harcoded the json response to `usersData` it works.

```
let usersData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "LG"
    "created_at": "2021-03-24T11:34:15Z",
    "status": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Samsung",
    "created_at": "2021-03-12T09:42:32Z",
    "status": 2
  }
]
```

Any mistake in calling the API?

Here's the full Table.js (modified from CoreUI React template)

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  CBadge,
  CCard,
  CCardBody,
  CCardHeader,
  CCol,
  CDataTable,
  CRow
} from '@coreui/react'
import { DocsLink } from 'src/reusable'
import axios from "axios";

let usersData = []
axios
  .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/monitor/list`)
  .then((res) => {
    usersData = res.data;
  })

const getBadge = status => {
  switch (status) {
    case '1': return 'success'
    case '2': return 'secondary'
    case '3': return 'warning'
    case '0': return 'danger'
    default: return 'primary'
  }
}

const fields = ['id','name', 'status']

const Tables = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <CRow>
        <CCol xs="12" lg="6">
          <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Simple Table
              <DocsLink name="CModal"/>
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
            <CDataTable
              items={usersData}
              fields={fields}
              itemsPerPage={5}
              pagination
              scopedSlots = {{
                'status':
                  (item)=>(
                    <td>
                      <CBadge color={getBadge(item.status)}>
                        {item.status}
                      </CBadge>
                    </td>
                  )

              }}
            />
            </CCardBody>
          </CCard>
        </CCol>

        <CCol xs="12" lg="6">
          <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Striped Table
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
            <CDataTable
              items={usersData}
              fields={fields}
              striped
              itemsPerPage={5}
              pagination
              scopedSlots = {{
                'status':
                  (item)=>(
                    <td>
                      <CBadge color={getBadge(item.status)}>
                        {item.status}
                      </CBadge>
                    </td>
                  )

              }}
            />
            </CCardBody>
          </CCard>
        </CCol>
      </CRow>

      <CRow>

        <CCol xs="12" lg="6">
          <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Condensed Table
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
            <CDataTable
              items={usersData}
              fields={fields}
              size="sm"
              itemsPerPage={5}
              pagination
              scopedSlots = {{
                'status':
                  (item)=>(
                    <td>
                      <CBadge color={getBadge(item.status)}>
                        {item.status}
                      </CBadge>
                    </td>
                  )

              }}
            />
            </CCardBody>
          </CCard>
        </CCol>

        <CCol xs="12" lg="6">
          <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Bordered Table
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
            <CDataTable
              items={usersData}
              fields={fields}
              bordered
              itemsPerPage={5}
              pagination
              scopedSlots = {{
                'status':
                  (item)=>(
                    <td>
                      <CBadge color={getBadge(item.status)}>
                        {item.status}
                      </CBadge>
                    </td>
                  )

              }}
            />
            </CCardBody>
          </CCard>
        </CCol>

      </CRow>

      <CRow>
        <CCol>
          <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Combined All Table
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
            <CDataTable
              items={usersData}
              fields={fields}
              hover
              striped
              bordered
              size="sm"
              itemsPerPage={10}
              pagination
              scopedSlots = {{
                'status':
                  (item)=>(
                    <td>
                      <CBadge color={getBadge(item.status)}>
                        {item.status}
                      </CBadge>
                    </td>
                  )
              }}
            />
            </CCardBody>
          </CCard>
        </CCol>
      </CRow>
        <CRow>
        <CCol>
          <CCard>
            <CCardHeader>
              Combined All dark Table
            </CCardHeader>
            <CCardBody>
            <CDataTable
              items={usersData}
              fields={fields}
              dark
              hover
              striped
              bordered
              size="sm"
              itemsPerPage={10}
              pagination
              scopedSlots = {{
                'status':
                  (item)=>(
                    <td>
                      <CBadge color={getBadge(item.status)}>
                        {item.status}
                      </CBadge>
                    </td>
                  )
              }}
            />
            </CCardBody>
          </CCard>
        </CCol>
      </CRow>
    </>
  )
}

export default Tables
```

Comment: I imagine the mistake is coming from your React code, would you care to post the full component code where you're fetching this data?

Comment: added the React code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use normal variable like `let usersData = []` reactjs will be unaware when your variable update and won't re-render your component. You need to use `useState` so reactjs will re-render your component when state changes, and you need to put your axios call inside the `useEffect` read more about *useEffect* [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#:%7E:text=What%20does%20useEffect%20do%3F,after%20performing%20the%20DOM%20updates.).

Your code will be like that:

```
const Tables = () => {
  const [usersData , setUsersData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/monitor/list`).then((res) => {
      setUsersData (res.data);
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
    //..
```